# RecyclerView jumps when scrolling variable height ComposeView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` that's hosting items rendered with Jetpack Compose. The height of the items varies. When scrolling from the top of the list to the bottom, scrolling is smooth. However, when scrolling back to the top, the items in the list jump when the height of the next item to appear at the top of the screen differs from the height of the item that was previously at the top of the screen.

The layout height of each `ComposeView` is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`. The previous XML layouts scrolled smoothly in both directions.

I am using Compose 1.2.0 and RecyclerView 1.3.0-beta01.

Is there a solution for having smooth scrolling in both directions?

Update: I have reported a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240449681) and provided a sample project demonstrating the problem [here](https://github.com/nstublen/jumping-recycler-view).

Comment: Have you tried using a LazyColumn instead of a recycling view?

Comment: @AugustoAlonso, using `LazyColumn` will resolve this problem and it is the long-term plan. We just have some item view types in this `RecyclerView` that we haven't yet migrated to Compose and I was hoping we could perform the migration one view type at a time without seeing significant issues.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but which version of Compose are you using?

I came across this in version [1.2.0-alpha06 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha06):

"Upgrading both RecyclerView and Compose will now result in much better scrolling performance for RecyclerViews with Compose views as children."

Maybe you need to update to the latest (1.2.0-alpha06 was released in March 2022)...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the original question to indicate I'm using Compose 1.2.0 and RecyclerView 1.3.0-beta01. I've also added links to where I filed a bug report and a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Suppose the item view is a ComposeView, do this in onBindViewHolder:

composeView.getChildAt(0)?.requestLayout()

This can fix the jumping. But it might have some performance impact. Make your own choice.

here is my item.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
</data>
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/composeItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</layout>
```

and do this in Adapter's onBindViewHolder():

```
findView<ComposeView>(R.id.composeItem).apply {
 // avoid wrapContent jump
    getChildAt(0)?.requestLayout()
    setContent {
       // your own Composable method
        Content()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code do exactly?